# Mobile Application Debugging on Xamarin Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

When I am trying to debug my application I am facing error which are given below

**error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140624\sdk\tools\zipalign.exe" is invalid.**

Kindly give me the solution to resolve it

Answer (score 1):

The new Android SDK moved some things around.
Install v19 or v20 using the Android SDK manager and then copy zipalign.exe from

> ...\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\20.0.0

to

> \AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools

Normally the full path will be something like

> C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\

I had the same issue, this resolved it.